# set up asyncio with getRequests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get asyncio working with my webscraper. I've gotten it working before but when I run it today the set_query does not return a sting

```
async def set_query(company):


    with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        #Create Query
        query = format_text(company)
        page = get(query)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,  'html.parser')
        #Get adress etc as string
        try:
            location = soup.find_all('address')[0].text
        except:
            location = soup.find_all('p')[0].text
        if "Din sökning på" in location or "Ingen träff på" in location:
            return

    return  location

def scrape():
    #Companies to scrape
    companies = getData()
    #Get Page
    count = 0
    for company in companies:
        try:
            location = set_query(company)
            print(location)
        except:
            print("")

        corp.update({company:get_adress(location)})
        save_to_excel()

def start_download():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    future = asyncio.ensure_future(scrape())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

The excpected result is to pass the location returned from set_query into get_adress but it's not passing in a string, error message from get_adress "This is exception  'coroutine' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to call ***asynchronous*** coroutine `set_query(company)` in synchronous way. 
Coroutine is *awaitable* object.

Make your `def scrape()` to be a coroutine that will awaits a result from another coroutine `set_query(company)`:

```
...

async def scrape():
    ...
    location = await set_query(company)
```

Moreover, `asyncio.ensure_future()` requires `Future/Task` instance as a main argument: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future

Comment: This got it working but I think that it is doing it synchronous

Comment: @J-Doe, also the presence of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `loop` is doubtful in your current `set_query` function. What's the point of using them there?

Comment: I'm new to all of this and when looking thought the internet it was what I found. It was working once so I thought I did it right.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-asynchronous-web-requests-in-parallel-with-python-3-5-without-aiohttp-264dc0f8546 this is where I got my solution from

Comment: @J-Doe, your version doesn't correlate with that you have mentioned. That example uses much more context and asynchronous calls